# Image as splashscreen for JavaFX application not hiding automatically

Tags: java, javafx, splash-screen

I have a simple .png image file that I wish to show while the JavaFX application is loading.

I am using NetBeans as my IDE and I know that splashscreen can be added like so:
Project properties -> Run -> VM Options: -splash:path-to-image

Now the splashscreen starts nicely, but it won't close after my application has started. Just sits there on the screen until I close my application completely.
As the documentation says (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) "The splash screen window is closed automatically as soon as the first window is displayed by Swing/AWT". JavaFX is not Swing nor AWT application. So how can I close it?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, answering my own question.

When splash is set in VM Options: -splash:path-to-image.
The in JavaFX I was able to close it like this:

```
//Get the splashscreen
final SplashScreen splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();

//Close splashscreen
    if (splash != null) {
        System.out.println("Closing splashscreen...");
        splash.close();
    }
```

Hope this is somewhat helpful to others also! ;)

Answer (score 0):

On AdoptOpenJDK 14, calling `SplashScreen.getSplashScreen()` throws a `HeadlessException`.

To work around this, I did:

```
    System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
    Optional.ofNullable(SplashScreen.getSplashScreen()).ifPresent(SplashScreen::close);
    System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
```

Answer (score -1):

While the accepted answer is correct, there is room to improve this a little bit. You shouldn't use the `final` keyword as this would make the splash image hang. In addition, instead of using the `null`, you can check whether the `splash` is visible by using the built in `isVisible()` method.

```java
import java.awt.*;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        SplashScreen splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();

        if (splash.isVisible()) {
            System.out.println("Is visible");

            splash.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your comment about the final keyword is plainly wrong.

Comment: Why do you think the `final` keyword wrong in my comment? Can you please elaborate? When I tested this on my end, the `final` keyword didn't work for me and it caused the Splash stuck.

Comment: Because it makes no difference when used on variables whatsoever. When the method returns, the object is unreferenced either way. A final keyword on variables is just a source-level feature, it has no effect on the generated bytecode.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but that's made a difference on my end. Using `final` keyword, it didn't work on my end.

Comment: I can't believe that, it does not on my end. I even compared the code on the bytecode level, its exactly the same. are you using a buggy / very old compiler maybe?

Comment: I left that project couple of months before due to some issue with Java but I can confirm that I was using latest Java.

Comment: I think that if you don't check that splash is not null and it is null then using 'splash.isVisible()' will cause an exception.